# Can't clone repository with git on windows

Tags: windows, git

I try to checkout repository on Windows 7 machine with git.exe:

```
C:/tmp>git --version
git version 2.12.0.windows.1

C:/tmp>git clone https://someuser@bitbucket.org/somcomp/someproj.git
Cloning into 'somproj'...
remote: Counting objects: 11762, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7028/7028), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (11762/11762), 48.36 MiB | 1.30 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 11762 (delta 5706), reused 10135 (delta 4230)
Resolving deltas: 100% (5706/5706), done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'someproj/node_modules/console-stamp/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/validate-npm-package-license/node_modules/spdx-correct/node_modules': No such file or directory
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'

C:\tmp>git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What can I do here? I tried **git config --system core.longpaths true** advice, but it doesn't help. Any other recipes? Failed folder doesn't seem to contain any ugly characters if I look at it in bitbucket and has only one child folder:

node_modules / console-stamp / node_modules / dateformat / node_modules / meow / node_modules / normalize-package-data / node_modules / validate-npm-package-license / node_modules / spdx-correct / node_modules / spdx-license-ids /

Thanx for any ideas.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a file in there with the same name but different case?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, no i don't see conflicts of this sort

Comment: Does any of the folder or file names end or start with a space?

Comment: I don't see any of this in bitbucket.

Comment: Something like ProcMon might help debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to **git version 2.12.2.windows.2** solved the problem for me, since this bug was fixed only recently.